# What is the right chain of events when displaying stored session data for client

Tags: php, javascript, html, session, session-cookies

Is my following chain is correct?

First I display the client home.php which will create a session and will store inside $_SESSION['name'] = 'random_name' and will Greet end user client:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name'] = 'random_name';
?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
        <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Greeting</h1>
        <a id="1" href="index.php">link</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Then I will press on the link which will take me to the second page index.php which will take me to another page which will display for user the value inside$_SESSION['name'] after certain logic inside the page will be executed as described below:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
        <script src="test.js"> </script>
        <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p id="para"></p>
       <input type="button" onclick="checkAuth()" value="submit">
   </body>
   </html>
```

Now when I press the button it will activate checkAuth() function inside test.js that will by using AJAX will retrieve from server side(damn.php) the value inside SESSION['name']:

```
 function checkAuth()
 {
       var xmlhttp;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
          var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
          document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = response;
       }
   }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","damn.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Now damn.php looks like that:

```
       <?php

          session_start();

          if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
                   echo $_SESSION['name'];
          }
```

My question is that the easiest way there is to do it in order to display the client the items inside
$SESSION is like that?

Is there a simpler way without using javascript at all? Is it also correct to insert session_start() in every page? or only from pages I want to retrieve the SESSION['items']?

Comment: You only need to use session_start() in PHP files where you are using $_SESSION. Most PHP applications tend to have a single file (such as header.php) which is included at the top all PHP files, and header.php would have session_start. My applications don't use sessions that much, so I don't do that. In fact, I do it just like you are, and I don't see why not. Except I use jQuery so the AJAX code is much less verbose. Oh, and you should use json_encode- which converts PHP data to JSON (JSON is based on JavaScript objects and the syntax is the same, just restricted for data).

Answer (score 0):

You could quite simply just have

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'foo';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['name']) ; ?>;
</script>
```

If you know that you're going to need a  particular bit of session data inside a web page, and that data's available at the time you're generating the page, then just embed that data. The only time you'd want to make an AJAX call to fetch the data is you think the data in the session might have changed before you actually need it in the javascript code.

`session_start()` is required anywhere you want to use $_SESSION to save/retrieve data. If a particular page doesn't need to modify or access session data, then you don't need to `session_start()` at all.

Comment: Nesting PHP code inside of JavaScript isn't right... You should write a compiler to do that sort of thing, or use AJAX to grab JSON-on-demand for larger data-sets.

Comment: @spencer: uh, why is it not right? php will execute on the server and will never been seen by the browser when it comes time to parse the javascript.

Comment: @Marc B: It's not right because over time that sort of code becomes unmanageable. Putting PHP tags in JavaScript is confusing, even if the PHP coder is also the JavaScript coder. The more you do this, the harder it is to read and understand the JavaScript code after stepping away for a few days or more and coming back. Since the problem worsens whenever the pattern is repeated, we call this an anti-pattern. Edit: You're not supposed to place PHP tags in HTML or CSS code either for the same reason, despite the fact that's one reason PHP is so popular in the first place..

Comment: @spencer: at some point, CODE has to be mixed in with the output scaffolding. it's absolutely unavoidable. Feel free to suggest a templating system, but then you're just swapping out raw PHP code for some **OTHER** programming syntax and end up with the same problem. I am NOT going to "pollute" a simple example with extra layers of garbage just to maintain someone's idea of code purity.

Comment: @Marc B: Different programming languages should communicate using text-streams. In the case of PHP and JavaScript, the stream could be HTTP or the Web-Socket protocol (although web-sockets are not well-supported quite yet). The type of text you got absolutely right- JSON.

Comment: that's fine, but like I said in my example, if the data doesn't change between page generation and data usage, then for efficiency embed it at generation time, instead of having to force yet ANOTHER full-blown http request down the user's throat. I'd rather get the candy bar at the store while I'm getting my groceries, instead of driving BACK to the store to buy it seperately.

Comment: @Alon Melanker: Yes, the way you are doing it is correct. Since you are sending plain-text data, using a plain-text type with HTTP/GET is perfect. If you were sending any data-type that is more complex (such as an object or array), using json_encode would make the procedure a little simpler.

Comment: @Marc B: As for your candy-bar example, if the data DOES change, then a request would be necessary. If the data does NOT change, then compiling would be better than doing it at generation time. For example, if you have an operation that consolidates JavaScript files into one minified file, that would be the time you append configuration settings and such to the top of the JavaScript file using code-generation. I don't save my JavaScript files with the intent of having server-side code embedded in them for caching reasons. As a side-note, I don't see how your solution would handle caching.

Comment: @MarcB: ... And your solution may be faster in most cases- I simply have not tested. The reason mixing two programming languages is an anti-pattern, however, has nothing to do with execution speed. It all revolves around speed of development. The two languages that are communicating should not know about each-other. Templating engines technically fall under this anti-pattern, too, since it requires some language A knows about some other language B- which is undesirable if you aim for loose-coupling.

Comment: I dont have much programming experience with JS and PHP but I had a feeling that mixing client side code with server side code is not right, I tend to agree with Spencer.